# Tally number of times string appears within a div

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sum

I have the below simple <html> page that highlights the times the '@' icon appears in an OnLoaded .txt file within a <div>

What I'd like to know is... how can can I take a count of the number of times the '@' string appears in that <div> ?

```js
var openFile = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var text = reader.result;
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    
    const lines = text.split('\n');
    lines.forEach((line) => {
      const div = output.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      const textSplitAroundAt = line.split('@');
      textSplitAroundAt.forEach((text, i) => {
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        if (i === textSplitAroundAt.length - 1) return;
        const span = div.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
        span.textContent = '@';
        span.className = 'colorize';
      });

    });
  };
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

```css
.colorize
{
 color: #f90;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>.TXT Log Parser</h1>
</center>

<center>
  <div id="populateNumbers">I would like the number of times '@' symbol appears here >>> ... </div> 
</center> 

<center>
  <h2><input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'></h2>
</center>
<br/>
<div id='output'>...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at the end of your `onload` event:

```
document.getElementById('populateNumbers').textContent = text.split('@').length - 1;
```

```js
var openFile = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var text = reader.result;
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    
    const lines = text.split('\n');
    lines.forEach((line) => {
      const div = output.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      const textSplitAroundAt = line.split('@');
      textSplitAroundAt.forEach((text, i) => {
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        if (i === textSplitAroundAt.length - 1) return;
        const span = div.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
        span.textContent = '@';
        span.className = 'colorize';
      });

    });
    document.getElementById('populateNumbers').textContent = text.split('@').length - 1;
  };
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

```css
.colorize
{
 color: #f90;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>.TXT Log Parser</h1>
</center>

<center>
  <div>I would like the number of times '@' symbol appears here: <span id="populateNumbers"> ... </span></div> 
</center> 

<center>
  <h2><input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'></h2>
</center>
<br/>
<div id='output'>...</div>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, and is super clear :)

Might sound like a silly question.. the div now contains the number count (which is great), but what would the best way of writing that line of code so that we see a 'string' followed by the sum of the lookup of that string?

Comment: Change the div to something like this:  `<div>I would like the number of times '@' symbol appears here: <span id="populateNumbers"> ... </span></div>`